# Pandas groupby week given a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have the following data sample:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-01-01','2011-01-02',
                       '2011-01-03','2011-01-04','2011-01-05',
                       '2011-01-06','2011-01-07','2011-01-08',
                       '2011-01-09','2011-12-30','2011-12-31'],
                   'revenue':[5,3,2,
                              10,12,2,
                              1,0,6,10,12]})

# Let's format the date and add the week number and year
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['week_number'] = df['date'].dt.week
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year

df

        date        revenue     week_of_year    year
0       2011-01-01  5           52              2011
1       2011-01-02  3           52              2011
2       2011-01-03  2           1               2011
3       2011-01-04  10          1               2011
4       2011-01-05  12          1               2011
5       2011-01-06  2           1               2011
6       2011-01-07  1           1               2011
7       2011-01-08  0           1               2011
8       2011-01-09  6           1               2011
9       2011-12-30  10          52              2011
10      2011-12-31  12          52              2011
```

I would like to compute the revenue per week, in order to later plot the results, and analyze the time series. The expected output would then be something like that :

```py
    week    revenue
0   1       8
1   2       33
2   52      22
```

I first thought of using the week number given by `timestamp.week`. 
However, I can't figure out how to deal with the ISO week number definition for the week preceeding week number 1. I am a bit confused, since grouping by `week_number` would in that case sum both the revenue at the very beginning of the year, and those at the end of the year.

Comment: Could you not group on year and week number?

Comment: I edited the question to show that the year given by `timestamp.year` is still 2011. That's where I don't understand anymore

Comment: Does `((df['date'] - pd.to_datetime('2011-01-01')).dt.days // 7) + 1` work instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you convert using dt.week , it is [ISO week date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372048/python-pandas-timestamp-week-returns-52-for-first-day-of-year).

You can using `strftime`

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.strftime('%W')).revenue.sum()
Out[588]: 
date
00     8
01    33
52    22
Name: revenue, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This wont work if you have > 1 year of data. (Ex: year 2022 -> first week will have number 1,  year 2023 -> first week will have number 1)

Comment: @Sergo055 strftime('%Y-%W')

Answer (score 4):

You could use `date` column as index and then resample the time series.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.resample('W').sum()
```

With that solution you don't even need the `week` and `year` column.

Comment: This works really nicely, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case you should be extremely carefull. If you want to have the weekly revenue for many years you might consider to move the first few days to the last week of 2010

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date =  pd.date_range(start="2011-01-01", end="2011-01-09")
date = [str(d)[:10] for d in date] + ["2011-12-30", "2011-12-31"]
rev =  np.random.randint(1,10, len(date))
df =  pd.DataFrame({"date": date, "rev":rev})
df["date"] =  df["date"].astype("M8[us]")

df["week"] = df["date"].dt.week
df["year"] = df["date"].dt.year
df["year"] = np.where((df["week"]==52) & (df["date"].dt.month==1), 
                      df["year"]-1,
                      df["year"])

df.groupby(["year", "week"])["rev"].sum()
```

If alternatively you are happy having a first `0` week you might consider to use this instead

```
df["week"] = np.where((df["week"]==52) & (df["date"].dt.month==1),
                      0, 
                      df["week"])
```