# How Do You Group a Date/Time Column by Weeks in Python?

Tags: python

I have a column in my dataset called "Published" that looks like the attached picture below. How do I group them by weeks so I can see all of the unique weeks of this column?
Output should look something like:
2017-11-06
2017-11-13
2017-11-20
...

[My Column "Published"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/negtS.png)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51105216/8881141) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45281297/8881141) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59246839/8881141) or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Date')
df.resample('W').agg({'column_name':'agg_function'})
```

Comment: This did not help. I'm getting TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: @Pikacho Yo [Datetime](https://youtu.be/UFuo7EHI8zc) series tutorial  .Also refer Pandas documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for help